# Koin constructor inject few parameters MVVM Android Architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, koin

I'm using MVVM architecture for my Android app and just started with Koin. When I'm trying to inject more than one parameter problems start appearing. 
For now I have `Repository` class which uses:

- `RESTApi` to perform web calls. `RestProvider` uses `SocketProvider` as constructor parameter for this
- `Utils(Context)` as helper to retrieve some basic information(appVersion,
  IMEI etc)

My appModule

```
    {
    single<RepositoryApi> {
        Repository(
            Utils(androidContext())
           \\ RestProvider(SocketProvider()) Here I get problems
        )
    }
    single<RestApi> { RestProvider(get() as SocketProvider) }
    single<SocketApi> { SocketProvider() }
    single<UtilsApi> { Utils(androidContext()) }
    viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
}
```

When I use `Utils` only everything works fine, when I add `RestProvider` I get exception:

> Caused by: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not
>   create instance for
>   [type:Single,primary_type:'com.etrans.ntsdriver.provider.repository.RepositoryApi']
>           at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:61)
>           at org.koin.core.instance.SingleDefinitionInstance.get(SingleDefinitionInstance.kt:40)
>           at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition.resolveInstance(BeanDefinition.kt:70)
>           at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:165)
>         at org.koin.core.scope.Sc

I understand that I'm missing something but I didn't find any tutorials or examples to explain such cases.

My gradle dependencies related to Koin(maybe will be useful):

```
 // Koin for Android - ViewModel features
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-java:$koin_version"

    testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
    androidTestImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using **Koin** to setup retrofit.

```
private val networkModule = module {

    single {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor(
            HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger { message ->
                //Logger.d("NETWORK: $message")
            }).apply {
            level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
        }
    }

    single {
        DefaultHeadersInterceptor()
    }

    single {
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(get<HttpLoggingInterceptor>())
            .addInterceptor(get<DefaultHeadersInterceptor>())
            .build()
    }

    single {

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()))
            .client(get())
            .build()
    }
    single { get<Retrofit>().create(ApiInterface::class.java) }
}
```

So on this way you can configure ApiInterface

> single { get().create(ApiInterface::class.java) }

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it today